# ObservableList not Copying

Tags: java, javafx

**EDIT**

Turns out that it appears that `FXCollections.observableArrayList()` is creating a shallow copy of my list when I actually want a deep copy. `this.value` and `value` "point" to two different `ObservableList`s, but the `String[]` they contain "point" to the same object rather than to copies.

**Original**

As part of an application I'm making, the user can open up the contents of an `ObservableList` and edit it. In order to allow them to cancel and discard any changes, I make a copy of this `ObservableList` and have them work on the copy. Then if they choose to save the changes, I update the variable for the `ObservableList` with the contents of the copy.

The copying is done using the function `setValues` below. This function belongs to the fx controller for the editing window, and is called by the controller of the main window.

```
public void setValues(ObservableList<String[]> values) {
    if (values == null) {
        this.values = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    } else {
        this.values = FXCollections.observableArrayList(values);
    }
    lstView.setItems(this.values);
}
```

As far as I have been able to find, the above code should create a copy of `values` so that `this.values` and `values` contain the same information but are not the same `ObservableList`. *However*, in practice the two still appear to be the same object, so any changes to `this.values` will also be made to `values`.

This is the only place where `this.value` is assigned a value. Anybody have any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

This is all done with JavaFX and Java 8.

Comment: Why are you saying that are the same object? Have you print the `toString()` of both objects and is the same?

Comment: @easyjoin.net, I am running the application in debug mode, and have set a breakpoint on the line where changes are saved to the "copy". As I step through that code I am looking at the memory and can see both the original and the "copy" changing where only the "copy" should change.

Comment: Then the error is in another place, not in the code you posted.

Comment: @easyjoin.net. See the edit.

Comment: So the `value` objects are different. Ok, now you know what you have to do :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list that is being copied contains references to arrays of Strings.
The copy only copies the first level of references - that is references to arrays rather than the string values in these arrays.

What we get after the copy are two independent lists that point to the same physical arrays with same strings.
Here is a code that demonstrates this behavior:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String [] a = {"aaa"};
        List<String[]> values = new LinkedList<>();
        values.add(a);

        List<String[]> v2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(values);

        String[] b = values.get(0) ;
        b[0] = "1";

        System.out.println(v2.get(0)[0]);
        System.out.println(values.get(0)[0]);
    }
}
```

Here is a solution that does a deeper copy:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String [] a = {"aaa"};
        List<String[]> values = new LinkedList<>();

        values.add(a);


        List<String[]> copy = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String[] stringArray : values) {
            String[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(stringArray, stringArray.length);
            copy.add(newArray);
        }


        values.get(0)[0] = "bbb";

        System.out.println(values.get(0)[0]);
        System.out.println(copy.get(0)[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :D